# How to connect to Azure D365 Odata via C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I am looking for a simple way to connect to an Azure Odata data store (specifically Dynamics365 for Finance and Operations) in a .NET console application (no browser involved) and retrieve odata json. I searched all over MS docs and finally found this:

```
public OAuthMessageHandler(string serviceUrl, string clientId, string redirectUrl, string username, string password, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler): base(innerHandler) {
  AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(serviceUrl + "/data/")).Result;
  AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ap.Authority, false);
  AuthenticationResult authResult;
  if (username != string.Empty && password != string.Empty) {

    UserCredential cred = new UserCredential(username, password);
    authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUrl, clientId, cred);
  } else {
    authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(serviceUrl, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), PromptBehavior.Auto);
  }

  authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
}
```

try/catch below is inside my console app's static `main` method and calls the function above:

```
try {
  messageHandler = new OAuthMessageHandler(serviceUrl, clientId, string.Empty, userName, password, new HttpClientHandler());

  using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(messageHandler)) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0); //2 minutes
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = client.GetAsync("api/data/v9.0/WhoAmI", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
      //Get the response content and parse it.  
      JObject body = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
      Guid userId = (Guid) body["UserId"];
      Console.WriteLine("Your system user ID is: {0}", userId);
    } else {
      throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  DisplayException(ex);
}
```

IMPORTANT: I am able to successfully connect to D365 F&O in a browser with the username and password that I have. And I am passing those into the function above. I also have a valid clientId. I know all these are valid because I have a 3rd-party app that, with the usn, pwd, clientId, and Authorization URL, I'm able to connect and interact with F&O and its odata. But I'm trying to replicate this interaction as simply as possible in my .NET console app.

I started out with [this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth) but ended up deviating and mixing in examples and approaches from other docs just to get it all to compile.

Here are my specifics, obfuscated as little as possible:

```
D365 F&O URL: https://mycustomer2492efd6bdevaos.cloudax.dynamics.com/
Odata URL: https://mycustomer2492efd6bdevaos.cloudax.dynamics.com/data/InventItemPrices
Client Id: c0bzae2e-5233-4465-a2f2-ceb87aa52c3f (I changed some chars)
Authorization URL: https://login.windows.net/mycustomer.com
```

And I have the username and password. I do not need a redirectUrl so I left that as empty string. I also don't need a client secret. (If I had client secret all this would be much simpler because I found simpler c# code samples to work with that.)

When I call the function above, I get this error:

> Invalid authenticate header format - Parameter name:
> authenticateHeader

The exception is thrown at this line:

```
AuthenticationParameters ap = AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(new Uri(serviceUrl + "/data/")).Result;
```

I am not married to the approach I'm using, it's just all I have found that actually compiles and attempts to work. I would greatly appreciate a self-contained function with as few dependencies as possible to connect to my odata and pull down the json as needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the OData endpoint over the SDK?

Comment: blockingHD: Not at all. Would prefer not to use SDK. Raw c# with no dependencies besides standard .NET would be great.

Comment: The URI needs to look like this 'private static string serviceUrl = https://yourorg.crm.dynamics.com'

Comment: jdweng: no, it's not crm. It's F&O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

```
string d365RootURL = "https://someenvironmentos.cloudax.dynamics.com";
string authorizationURL = "https://login.windows.net/something.com";
var usn = "serviceAcctUsn";
var pwd = "serviceAcctPwd";
var clientID = "c0bcae....6aa52c3f";
string d365OdataURL = d365RootURL + "/data/";
string odataQuery = "SomeEntity?ItemNumber%20eq%20%27999";

UserCredential creds = new UserPasswordCredential(usn, pwd);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorizationURL, false);
var authTask = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(d365RootURL, clientID, creds);

try {
  authTask.Wait();
} catch (Exception ex) {

}

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authTask.Result;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(d365OdataURL);

var response = httpClient.GetAsync(odataQuery).Result;
```

Answer (score -2):

The URI need to look like this :

```
private static string serviceUrl = "https://yourorg.crm.dynamics.com";
```

Comment: No, this is not CRM. It's D365 Finance and Operations, as mentioned in original post.